# Javascript: OS-Detection … if on linux

Tags: javascript, jquery, linux

this does not work for me … anything wrong?

```
    var linux = false;
    if ( navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Linux")!=-1 ) 
        linux = true;
```

Is there an easier jQuery Way to to this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to know if the user agent runs – or pretends to run – under Linux?

Comment: You mean any other way that actually works? :)

Comment: @knittl for some flashbug under linux!

Comment: I know turntable.fm does this.  Maybe take a peak at their javascript and see if you find anything helpful?

Comment: @Dave Can't check out turntable.fm because it's not available in my country, sry.

Comment: @VladLazarenko You mean that should actually work? Because apperantly it doesn't!

Comment: Try using [`navigator.platform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.navigator.platform).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use [`navigator.platform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.navigator.platform) to get this.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of navigator.appVersion, try navigator.oscpu, or navigator.platform?

Although I'd be careful about showing different content for different os/browsers, it's better to directly test for the feature you're working with rather than give a blanket statement "show error, or, use this instead, for x/y/z browser", which *currently* may not be working with some feature.